# Kafka Streams unable to store Window Aggregations in-memory

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I have used following state-store configuration for window aggregations state-store to keep it in-memory and disable its logging. This state-store is used with window operation to store its intermediate aggregations.

```
 StateStoreSupplier winStoreSupplier =
      Stores.create("win-inmemory")
        .withKeys(Serdes.String())
        .withValues(aggrMessageSerde)
        .inMemory()
        .disableLogging()
        .build();
```

But with these settings kafka streams streams stores intermediate aggregations in changelog topic in disk. This slows down whole window operation. What settings should I use to store these intermediate window aggregations in-memory?

Comment: Currently not supported: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4730